# How to use image in WPF progressbar?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, progress-bar

I have a picture, I want to use it in WPF as a progressbar.

Please look at the image to understand this.

The code below, repeated the image.

[image]

The moving progress-box above the progressbar.

[image]

## I have tried this

```
<ControlTemplate
x:Key="ImageProgressBarTemplate"
TargetType="ProgressBar">    
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger
        RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard
                x:Name="str">
                <RectAnimation
                    x:Name="quatanim"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="imgbrush"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ImageBrush.Viewport)"
                    From="0,0,36,36"
                    To="36,0,36,36"
                    Duration="0:0:5"
                    AutoReverse="False"
                    RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>

<!-- Custom progress bar goes here -->
<Border
    Name="PART_Track"
    Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
    CornerRadius="0"
    Padding="1.5">

    <Grid>
        <!-- Rounded mask (stretches to fill Grid) -->
        <Border
            Name="mask"
            Background="#EEEEEE"
            CornerRadius="0" />

        <!-- Any content -->

        <Rectangle
            Name="PART_Indicator"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">    
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush
                    Visual="{Binding ElementName=mask}" />
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>    
            <Rectangle.Fill>    
                <ImageBrush
                    x:Name="imgbrush"
                    ImageSource="/myproject;component/Assets/myimage.png"
                    AlignmentX="Left"
                    Stretch="Fill"
                    TileMode="Tile"
                    AlignmentY="Top"
                    ViewportUnits="Absolute"
                    Viewport="0,0,36,36"
                    ViewboxUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox"
                    Viewbox="0,0,1,1">
                </ImageBrush>    
            </Rectangle.Fill>    
        </Rectangle>    
    </Grid>    
</Border>
```

```
<ProgressBar Template="{StaticResource ImageProgressBarTemplate}"/>
```

The all that I need is a detailed tutorial of how to use image in wpf progressbar for this kind of images.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Now updated, please see.

Comment: @RupamBhaduri did You manage to solve this? I really like both progressbars and I'd like to use something similar

Answer (score 1):

You have to design your own template of progressbar.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
  <Canvas>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="pgbar" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" 
                 Value="{TemplateBinding Value}" 
                 Minimum="{TemplateBinding Minimum}"
                 Maximum="{TemplateBinding Maximum}"/>

    <Image Source="image.PNG" Canvas.Left="{TemplateBinding Value}">
      <Image.RenderTransform>
         <!-- width / 2 and height /2-->
         <TranslateTransform X="-56" Y="-25"/>
      </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
  </Canvas>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: The Canvas.Left="" just sets the progress as an px value, I think this won't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

An improvement for the answer of Klaus Fischer:

Here is the ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding ProgressbarValue}" Template="{StaticResource Progressbar2}" />
```

And here is the template (See post of Klaus Fischer):

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Progressbar2" TargetType="ProgressBar">
<Canvas >
<ProgressBar x:Name="pgbar" Visibility="Hidden" Width="{Binding ElementName=StatusGrid,Path=ActualWidth}" Background="Transparent" Value="{TemplateBinding Value}" />
<Image Source="Resources/Images/running.png" Height="42px" Canvas.Left="{TemplateBinding Value, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference pgbar}}" />
</Canvas>
</ControlTemplate>
```

As you can see, there is a converter in the

> Canvas.Left

property.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
     var bar = ((System.Windows.Controls.ProgressBar) parameter);
     var percentPixe = bar.ActualWidth/100;
     return percentPixe*(double) value-42;
}
```

The expression

> value-42

handles the size of the image, otherwise the image would be in front of the real ProgressBar.

This should do the job.